# Bootstrap bundle js not working in Laravel Inertia.Js Vue 3

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I have a project with Laravel Vue 3, Inertia.Js. In app.js i have already import bootstrap bundle.

My app.js code:

```
import { createApp, h } from 'vue'
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3'
import { InertiaProgress } from '@inertiajs/progress'
import bootstrap from 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle' //HERE

createInertiaApp({
  resolve: name => require(`./Pages/${name}`),
  setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
    createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
      //set mixins
      .mixin({
        methods: {

          //method "hasAnyPermission"
          hasAnyPermission: function (permissions) {

            //get permissions from props
            let allPermissions = this.$page.props.auth.permissions;

            let hasPermission = false;
            permissions.forEach(function(item){
              if(allPermissions[item]) hasPermission = true;     
            });

            return hasPermission;
          },

          //title
          title() {
            return "Sistem Data"
          },

        },
      })
      .use(plugin)
      .use(bootstrap) //USE BOOTSTRAP
      .mount(el)
  },
});

InertiaProgress.init()
```

and my frontend.blade.php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="Web Name" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="{{ mix('/css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="{{ asset('/css/offcanvas.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.2/dist/leaflet.css"
     integrity="sha256-sA+zWATbFveLLNqWO2gtiw3HL/lh1giY/Inf1BJ0z14="
     crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
        <style>
            /* Sticky footer styles
            -------------------------------------------------- */
            html {
                position: relative;
                min-height: 100%;
            }
            body {
                margin-bottom: 60px;
            }
            .footer {
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 60px; 
                background-color: #f5f5f5;
            }
        </style>
</head>

<body class="h-100">
  @inertia
</body>

</html>
```

The CSS is working, but the javascript is not working. I want to make dropdown menu and submenu like screenshot below:

[image]

But the toggle is not working.

My package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.25",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^5.0.0",
        "sass": "^1.56.1",
        "sass-loader": "^12.6.0",
        "vue-loader": "^16.8.3"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@inertiajs/inertia": "^0.11.0",
        "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3": "^0.6.0",
        "@inertiajs/progress": "^0.2.7",
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
        "@vueform/multiselect": "^2.5.6",
        "bootstrap": "^5.2.2",
        "chart.js": "^3.9.1",
        "leaflet": "^1.9.2",
        "leaflet-sidebar-v2": "^3.2.3",
        "vue": "^3.2.29",
        "vue-chart-3": "^3.1.8",
        "vue-sweetalert2": "^5.0.2"
    }
```

Comment: did y get fix, im also having same problem i dont get any solution

Comment: yes, check at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/vite/ and follow number 3 and 4. Then in ```webpack.mix.js``` use that ```.sass('resources/sass/app.scss','public/css')```